# C# Word VSTO/Interop: Table Row over two pages and vertical text alignment problem

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I am currently struggling with finding a proper solution for following problem:
Imagine you have an MS Word (2019) document containing a table consisting of two columns 'A' and 'B'. Text in column B shall always be aligned vertically with the last text line of the text in column 'A'. OK, easy task if the row is on one page only: simply set vertical text alignment of 'B' to 'bottom' and you're done.

Now the BUT: If the the text in 'A' gets too long, Word shall break the cell across pages (hat's a mandatory requirement!). But even if the long text in column 'A' now ends on page 2, the short text in 'B' will be placed on bottom of page 1!

A possible workaround would be to fill up the 'B' with multiple LFs and/or LF+CRs, but I hope someone can explain how a proper solution could look like?!

Thanks in advance!

[Desired text position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKYJX.jpg)

[Wrong text position if row is split across 2 pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FLMW.jpg)